# How do we calculate between numbers when we've got the start and end number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm slow studying the math.

I'm trying to calculate the numbers with given start and end number.

For example,

What if there are 256 numbers as 0,1,2,3,4,5...255.

and I just only know if 0 then 9 and if 255 then 3.

Then how do we calculate between the numbers (1), (2), (3)..(254)?

more example,
what if there are 4 numbers as the below.

1,2,3,4

What if we give start and end number for this example. (1)= 1 and (4)=4
then we can calculate (2)=2, (3)=3.
but what if start without 1, then how do we know?

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. Try to write precisely and avoid using shorthand. Also, a complete example that includes both what is given and what the correct answer would be might help get the point across (especially if you are having trouble explaining what you are trying to do).

Comment: This is not clear at all.  What is $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many answers to your problem.

If you only know f(x) for two values of x, you have many different choices for other values of f(x).

You need a formula for f(x) or you  may interpolate your data to fit a curve through your data.

For example You may fit a straight line through  the two points  $(0,9)$ and $(255,3)$   that you have and use that to find f(x) for other values.

Comment: Thanks Would you let me know with example for understanding?

Comment: Your slope is (3-9)/(255-0) = -6/255. Thus your equation is f(x)=(-6/225)(x)+9.

Comment: Thanks, you save my life, what I've looking for this .

Comment: You deserve some kind of "mindreader" badge for this answer, given that you've managed to decipher that question and actually give an answer that's accepted.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, you are very kind.